# Beyond the beyond

Tags: riddle

Beyond the beyond
In far reaches of flight
Scarcely seen without a fight
Broken packed cosmic twist
Feathers splayed in the mist
Strange wonder to behold
To gaze upon it is bold
Never lightly come upon it
For if you do, you may vomit
Your senses reeling in a flurry
Run you will try, in a hurry
But run and escape you cannot
You'll be eaten before you can rot
To gaze upon the humanlike face
You won't live to see your race

hint:

> I am African

hint continued:

> Wow, this riddle seems almost obvious to me.  I am tempted to post the answer.  Are you sure you guys don't know any African mythological creatures who eat people and have feathers and a humanlike face?

Comment: entire description fits "Devil"

Comment: Respectfully, Vikram, the devil is not known to eat people.  At least, growing up, I just thought of him as the lord of evil and king of hell.  His minions did the dirty work, he just seems to supervise the torture.

Comment: The grimreaper ?

Comment: this one likely has too many okay-ish answers. the clues are just too vague and apply to a lot of things.

Comment: although with the hint I'm thinking it might be a flag from a country in Africa. something about fighting and feathers.

Comment: I posted another hint that should make it obvious, since it ties together all of the clues.  This is a creature that all of you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are you sure you guys don't know any African mythological creatures who eat people and have feathers and a humanlike face?

Purely based on that,

> This has to be referring to the mythological [sphinx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx) and the Great Sphinx of Giza: [image]

I don't see how this comes from the riddle though.

Comment: Yes, this riddle really only had 3 clues in it.  Feathers, eat people, humanlike face.  It was supposed to be an easy and quick riddle, but I was wrong.  Now I know you guys don't like this style.

Comment: It's also a bit ironic, given that the Sphinx is maybe the oldest and most iconic riddler.

Comment: I am quite relieved that this one is finally solved, thank you for that. Maybe now I will stop getting negative votes on it, lol.  It was close to being suspended.

Answer (score 1):

Most lines I believe could point to a

> **black hole**

in a fairly straightforward way.

Beyond the beyond
In far reaches of flight

> Massive distances away

Broken packed cosmic twist

> 'Cosmic', 'broken' relating to a black hole being a hole in space

Never lightly come upon it,
For if you do, you may vomit,
Your senses reeling in a flurry,
Run you will try, in a hurry,
But run and escape you cannot,
You'll be eaten before you can rot

> ! If you come upon a black hole, you are more than likely going to be unable to escape, made a mess of and 'eaten' into it.
>   To gaze upon the humanlike face
>   You won't live to see your race
>   ! Unsure of the 'humanlike face' but if you gaze upon it, you're not going to escape (live) to see anyone again.

Answer (score 1):

okay I get it now it's this thing

> [image: african creature]

Answer (score 0):

Answer is

> Robot pirates from outer space

Beyond the beyond
In far reaches of flight
Broken packed cosmic twist

> in space, duh. also they have a flying ship.

Scarcely seen without a fight
Feathers splayed in the mist

> pirates fight, also some of them wear feathers because why not

Strange wonder to behold
To gaze upon it is bold
Never lightly come upon it
For if you do, you may vomit
Your senses reeling in a flurry

> you might get seasick also you can't outrun them.

Run you will try, in a hurry
But run and escape you cannot
You'll be eaten before you can rot
To gaze upon the humanlike face
You won't live to see your race

> they are aliens so they will kidnap you and probe you

Answer (score 0):

is it the

> flag of uganda?

it has feathers. and uganda has a lot of flight and fight in it's history I guess. and you can't outrun them because they run very fast. although vomiting when gazing upon the flag is not a very ncie thing to say

> [image: flag of uganda]